# Time.zone works on API but not on workers

Tags: ruby, timezone, ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm building an API using Grape framework and I want to set default timezone for the whole app as `UTC` so that when I call `Time.zone.now` I get the proper time

My `config/application.rb` looks like:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'api'))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'app'))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))

require 'bundler/setup'

Bundler.require :default, ENV['RACK_ENV']

Time.zone = 'UTC'

require_rel '../app'
require_rel '../api'
require_rel '../lib'
require_rel 'initializers'
```

If I start it up through `bundle exec rackup -p 3000` or `bin/console` and call `Time.zone.now` I get the proper time: `Fri, 05 Apr 2019 00:47:23 UTC +00:00`

Although, when I'm using a Sidekiq worker or something outside Rack itself (`bundle exec sidekiq -r ./config/application.rb`) and try to call `p Time.zone`, `nil` is returned and `Time.current` returns time with my timezone: `2019-04-04 21:48:57 -0300`
, even though I'm requiring `application.rb` which contains `Time.zone = 'UTC'` statement

How do I set UTC timezone globally for my workers as well?

### EDIT #1 - Worker Code

It's a simple worker: it just prints `Time.now` or `Time.zone.now`

```
module Cron
  class Date
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    JOB_NAME = 'date_job'

    def perform(start_date = 1.day.ago, end_date = Time.current)
      p [Time.now, Time.current]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you provide mode details / code  about the worker job?

Comment: @dharmesh done...

Answer (score 0):

You can just introduce an `ApplicationWorker` and have all other workers inherit from that class. In this new parent class, you can do everything that all workers have in common.

When you have two workers like this

```
class FooWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform
    # do something
  end
end

class BarWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform
    # do something else
  end
end
```

then you can use inheritance like this:

```
class ApplicationWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  Time.zone = 'UTC'
end

class FooWorker < ApplicationWorker
  def perform
    # do something
  end
end

class BarWorker < ApplicationWorker
  def perform
    # do something else
  end
end
```

Comment: it still doesn't work: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'now' for nil:NilClass`